# SOLVED - Cannot find/load .dll module

Tags: python, windows, dll

When trying to load a .dll file with

```
os.add_dll_directory("C:\\path\\to\\file")
library = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("C:\\path\\to\\file\\tdcbase.dll")
```

I get following error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\path\to\file\tdcbase.dll' (or one of its dependencies).
Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

I'm trying to run it with Python 3.9.7 on Windows11 (on Windows10 it also didn't work).
Using other Python versions (3.6, 3.7 and 3.8) did not change anything either.
Also, I don't think that there are any dependencies whose directory would need to be added.

There is also a 32-bit version of that file (tdbase.dll). When I try to load this with my 64-bit machine, I get following error message:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

So it seems as if it can recognise that it is the wrong bit number, i.e. it **can** find the file, but in the case of 64-bits not?

Can anyone see where the problem lies?

EDIT: After installing an additional usb driver, which was needed to speak to the connected instrument, the library could be loaded and everything works fine now.